# userInteractionEnabled = NO; except for one sub button

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to create a floating button wrapped in a UIViewController.
A floating button like: https://material.google.com/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html#

But how can I make only the button respond to touches?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    UIButton *closeButton  = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [closeButton addTarget:self
                    action:@selector(aMethod:)
          forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [closeButton setTitle:@"Back"
                 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    closeButton.frame = CGRectMake(30.0, 30.0, 100.0, 30.0);
    [self.view addSubview:closeButton];

    self.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    closeButton.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
}
```

Update: I added a sub class of UIView called MyView and added:

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UIView *hitTestView = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
    if (hitTestView == self) {
        hitTestView = nil;
    }

    NSLog(@"%@", hitTestView);

    return hitTestView;
}
```

and in the ViewController ViewDidLoad added this as the first line:

```
self.view = [[MyView alloc] init];
```

The NSLog shows always (null)

Comment: What is a "floating" button?

Comment: @matt I guess OP wants to "disable" the whole view except the closeButton, making that closeButton feels like "floating" above the "background" view which the user cannot touch.

Comment: You could override `pointInside:withEvent:` to only return true if if the point is in the button.  Setting `userInteractionEnabled` to no on the button's superview will prevent the button from getting touch events.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't going to work:

```
[self.view addSubview:closeButton];
self.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
closeButton.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

If `self.view` is not enabled, then its subviews are not enabled. And `closeButton` is its subview.

However, there is a workaround. You override `hitTest:withEvent:` for `self.view` to call super and return `nil` if the view that it receives is anything but the button, and to return the button if it *is* the button. Now only the button is touchable.

If you don't want to do that, here's a simpler way: put an almost-invisible view containing the button in front of everything, with `userInteractionEnabled` equal to `true`. The almost-invisible view has a background color with an `alpha` that is a *little* bigger than 0 — just enough to receive touches, but not enough that the user can see it. Now touches do not fall through it, and only the button is tappable. (Or let the user see it! A dark translucent background view is quite normal — just like what a UIAlertController does.)

Comment: Thanks, I am sure this is the way to go - I have updated the question as I can not get the "hitTest" to return the view that I press.

Comment: Because you didn't turn `userInteractionEnabled` back on?